# IPFS http server is refusing connection

Tags: node.js, ipfs, ipfs-http-client

I have used `ipsf-http-client` package to be able to save files into IPFS. I run the daemon through `ipfs daemon`. I can see that IPFS is working on my server instance.
And in my local environment everything is fine and works as expected. but I have an issue in the server. Here is a traceback:
[image]

I would like to ask for any tips or help in this matter as I have been entirely stuck on it.

Comment: can you try with axios?

Comment: fixed it by using configuration for multiaddr:  
// or connect with multiaddr  
`const ipfs = create('/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/5001')`

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it by using configuration for multiaddr:
"// or connect with multiaddr"
`const ipfs = create('/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/5001')`